# php mail() from godaddy server

Tags: php, email

I'm using godaddy for hosting my site and using default godaddy mail service.
Now i want to sent email using php mail function  to other email address from my 1 of my 15 email address of my godaddy's email accounts

How can i fix that from which email address email will be sent and how to place the username and password for the email address ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the mail() function, which just calls the OS mail function (i.e. sendmail), try something like SwiftMail (free PHP mail library). It support many different ways of sending mail, including logging into a mail account and sending email, just like you would do from your own computer. You could even send email from a gmail account if you wanted.

http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: it requires php 7, there are still some shared hosting that only offer php 5

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. It won't work because GoDaddy blocks connections to external SMTP servers, and no amount of switching libraries will help. You must either send via your local mail server which then relays through GoDaddy's servers, or send via SMTP directly through their servers. You can categorically not send through gmail using swiftmailer (or any other library) on GoDaddy hosts.

Comment: Please look at the date of the post. This approach was valid in 2011.

Answer (score 8):

The PHP `mail` function uses the mailserver configured for that webhost. You can't change that. Since **godaddy** controls the mailserver they control what headers it sends. You could try inserting a custom `From` header but I doubt that will work. It will either get modified, flagged as spam, or rejected.

If you have 15 accounts at **godaddy**, perhaps it's time to look for a more serious hosting solution?

Comment: so does this mean that you leave the from empty field and let goddady take care of it?
their support info is a joke, it's telling me the from field can't be @gmail, hotmail, yahoo, msn, etc. etc.
So if I leave it blank, it should work?

Comment: I hate godaddy! xD

Answer (score 1):

I am using godaddy hosting . Just keep some fields blank and send mail it will work .
please see below code its working for me.

```
<?php
include("class.phpmailer.php");
function sendMail($address,$username,$body){
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            //$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                // 1 = errors and messages
                                                                           // 2 = messages only
            // $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            // $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
            // $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets  as the SMTP server
            // $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the server
            // $mail->Username   = "xyz@gmail.com";  // username
            // $mail->Password   = "test121232";            // password

            $mail->SetFrom('contact@example.co.in', 'Contact');

            $mail->Subject    = "Enquiry for tour and travels package";



            $mail->MsgHTML($body);

            $address = $address;
            $mail->AddAddress($address, $username);
            $mail->AddCC('contact@example.co.in');

            if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
            echo "Message sent!";
            }
}

?>
```

just changed from email address, so you can send mail through this email id.

```
$mail->SetFrom('youremail@example.co.in', 'Contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue on a couple of client accounts.
After MUCH playing around, I found that it didn't matter what email app or code you use.
I finally compared two accounts. One where I know email sends from PHP, and one where it doesn't. The difference I found was:

Working account had these 2 dns entries on the domain:

- CNAME  /  mail  / @
- MX    /   @   /  mail.yourdomainname.com

And the MX Entry set within CPanel Zone Editor of:

- Destination: yourdomainname.com

The account that was NOT working was the same, except it did not have the CNAME entry mentioned above. I added it, waited a few minutes and tested my code again and I finally started receiving the emails from my code!

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

I asked Godaddy and support they told me to use relays. So Instead of using mail() function, I used PHPMailer. Kindly check below the configuration for PHP Mailer.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->setFrom('from@mail.com', 'From Mail');
$mail->addAddress('to@mail.com', 'To Mail');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML("test body 123"); 
$mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported'; 

if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Note: Here from@mail.com is my mail ID which is in cPanel mail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is the website hosted with GoDaddy or do you just have email hosting with them? Our website is hosted with GoDaddy *and* we have our email with them as well.

Assuming you have both, then this will need to be your configuration:

```
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      
$mail->isSMTP();                           
$mail->Host = localhost;                
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                 
$mail->Username   = SMTP_EMAIL;            
$mail->Password   = SMTP_PASSWORD;         
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none';
$mail->Port         = 25;


//Recipients
$mail->From = "hello@mygodaddyhosteddomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "MyGoDaddyHostedDomain";
$mail->addAddress(RECIPIENT_EMAIL, RECIPIENT_NAME);
```

GoDaddy assured me that security precautions are unnecessary such as SMTPAuth and SMTPSecure when your site is hosted with them and you are using their email services to send mail from a contact form.